# Redirect to https not working with .htaccess

Tags: redirect, htaccess, https

I have the following setup in my `.htaccess` file, but I am still able to go to my site via `http:`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've put the code in the wrong place. The HTTP to HTTPS directives must go *before* the WordPress front-controller, otherwise it's simply never going to get processed for anything other than direct file requests.

Your custom directives should also be outside the `# BEGIN WordPress` block, otherwise WordPress itself is likely to override your directives in a future update.

For example:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]    
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It is a "redirect", not a "rewrite". Change the `R` to `R=301` when you are sure it's working OK (as this should ultimately be a *permanent* redirect).

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the `[L]` flag for mod_rewrite? It "causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed".

See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Note that that your rewrite rules above the http->https rule employ this flag. These rules look like WordPress' rules that redirect requests that aren't for a specific file or directory to `index.php` for handling.

One idea is changing the order so your rules appear after `Rewrite Engine On` so the http-vs-https check is performed first, the redirect can take place, and *then* on the following redirected request (which will now be https) the following set of rules related to WordPress functionality can apply.

You could also try writing `RewriteCond {HTTPS} != on` as `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` and your `RewriteRule` line as `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` to be more explicit and send an http 301 (permanent) redirect status code back.

EDIT: I just saw MrWhite's comment, we were writing at the same time. He also has good advice: put your revised rules outside of the #WORDPRESS comment block so future WordPress updates will not clobber them!